# How to commit both modules to the same git hub repository in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have the project with two modules in IntelliJ IDEA:
[image: project]

My goal is to commit both of them to the same GitHub repository. Unfortunately i can’t figure out how can i do it.

In Git section, IJ duplicates my commits and separates them for two distinct modules. As a result, IJ also wants me to commit each module to the separe repository.

[image: git]

Googling by "Two modules in the same git hub repo" did not get any fresh results. Only some outdated tutorials back from 2014.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  Git just keeps track of files, and it has no knowledge of your module structure whatsoever.  What's your appetite for deleting the .git folder and starting fresh?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that these two modules have different repositories, therefore IDE shows you different logs.

From the git standpoint, I believe, Git detects these folders as two different repositories as well. In order to be able to commit to the same GitHub repository this modules should share a single Git repository or you might want to configure submodules in this case.